# как изменить поведение HttpClient?

Tags: c#

Делаю 2й запрос и возвращается статус код 302

Если устанавливаю задержку между первым и вторым запросом, то получаю статус код 200

Тупо получив 302 чуть позже сделать новый запрос ? Или можно предпринять что то ещё ?

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new()
{
   AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.Brotli,
   AllowAutoRedirect = true
};

HttpClient httpClient = new(httpClientHandler);

.........

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
        
int responseHttpStatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
    
string otvet = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Странно, у вас же стоит `AllowAutoRedirect = true`, должно следовать редиректам.

Comment: Возможно, у вас эта проблема: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405515/276994? Посмотрите, куда происходит редирект.

Comment: @VladD после прочтения ссылки проверил, действительно, делаю запрос на `https,` получаю `StatusCode: 302`, а в `Location: http://...` И что можно предпринять ?

Comment: Ну, для начала, редирект с защищённого соединения на незащищённое — это какая-то непонятная фигня, вы-то ожидаете защищённое соединение, а вам предлагают незащищённое, то есть потери в безопасности. Согласны ли вы с этим (а также ваши пользователи)?

Comment: Обратите внимание, в ответе была опечатка, исправил (нужно было `newRequest` вместо `request`).

Comment: @VladD Спасибо! С такой мелочью разобрался бы, я больше хотел понять, может какая то надстройка есть помимо `AllowAutoRedirect = true`, а получается надо ручками по `Location` проходить. При первом запросе я как бы серверу говорю создай документ, а при втором запросе хочу его посмотреть, но сервер ещё не успевает его создать, а я уже обращаюсь, вот и шлёт меня куда подальше, вот только косяк что на `http` перенаправляет(

Comment: `И что можно предпринять ?` отказаться от обмена данными с сервером, который имеет такие нарушения в безопасности.

Comment: @Алексей: По идее, после POST должна возвращаться ссылка на (успешно) созданный объект. Если они так не делают, или выдают ответ до реального создания, то они поступают нехорошо. https://restfulapi.net/http-status-201-created/

Comment: @VladD по идеи да, так и происходит в браузере. Отправляю форму и через некоторое время перекидывает на документ. Но повторив отправку формы с помощью `POST`, мне возвращается только `id` будущего документа со `StatusCode: 200`, а перенаправление на готовый документ не происходит. Вот и делаю запрос сам, используя этот `id`. Я пока слабо разбираюсь в `POST/GET`, возможно сам что то не так делаю. Но реальный пример продемонстрировать пока не могу(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите, в чём проблема.

Вас перенаправляют (redirect) с защищённого соединения (HTTPS) на незащищённое (HTTP). Это не очень-то хорошо, вот .NET и не делает авто-редирект. (Это поведение обсуждается [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23801).) И я бы тоже не советовал, т. к. вы снижаете безопасность для ваших пользователей, и информацию «в пути» (например, пароли, если вы их передаёте) сможет читать кто угодно.

---

На тот редкий случай, если вам можно игнорировать проблемы с безопасностью, делайте ручной редирект на Location из ответа:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new(httpClientHandler);
// в реальном коде создавайте HttpClient в начале работы приложения,
// а не перед каждым запросом
HttpResponseMessage response = null;
try
{
    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request,
                                           HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

    const int maxRedirects = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxRedirects &&
                    response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect &&
                    response.Headers.Location != null; i++)
    {
        // следуем редиректу
        using var newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(request.Method,
                                                      response.Headers.Location)
        {
            /* установите другие нужные свойства тут */
        };
        response.Dispose(); // старый ответ уничтожаем
        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(newRequest,
                                              HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
    }

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
    {
        // с нами что, в собачки играют?
        // слишком много редиректов, выбрасываем исключение
    }

    // и если другие ошибки, тоже
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string otvet = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
finally
{
    response?.Dispose(); // не забываем освободить ресурсы
}
```

Поскольку мы переиспользуем переменную `response`, мне пришлось вместо удобной конструкции `using` использовать более многословное `try/finally`.

---

Заметьте, что если вы пользуетесь не `ReadAsStringAsync`, а `ReadAsStreamAsync`, вам нужно отложить уничтожение `response` до того момента, как вы вычитаете весь Stream, иначе Stream тоже будет уничтожен.

---

Как подсказывает в комментариях @aepot, `HttpClient` не нужно создавать/уничтожать (`Dispose`) на каждый запрос, его стоит создать в начале работы и хранить до тех пор, пока он нужен (например, до конца жизни приложения). Литература по теме: [[1]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks), [[2]](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

Comment: @aepot: Спасибо, дописал.

Comment: @aepot: Ага, и там обновил, спасибо!